# What is it called when I have UBUNTU installed in hard-computer?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, windows, cpu

I want to know what should I call the fact of having Ubuntu installed in the computer itself. I installed it removing windows because I want to install windows on Virtualbox instead. I am not interested on installing windows at all on A Flash Drive, I will be using windows virtually only.

Thanks Friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Desktop on disk? Or alternatively, your host machine is running Ubuntu, while the Windows will be said to be running on a VM.